# Mockito/Spring: mock only one function from Autowired Service

Tags: spring, junit, mockito

i want mock only one function on a real service, this is Injected via @Autowired (Integration Test) ->

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = OrderitBackendApp.class)
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@WithUserDetails
public class OrderResourceIT {

    @Autowired
    private OrderRepository orderRepository;
    
    ...mor Injections and Tests
```

Here the mock functionalty ->

```
    @BeforeEach
    public void initTest() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        order = createEntity(em);
        OrderService spy = spy(orderService);
        when(spy.priceIsIncorrect(any())).thenReturn(false);
    }
```

But this and a few other things that i tried didnt work. What is the right way to do it ?

Comment: What exactly does `this and a few other things didn't work` mean?

Comment: I try it with Annotations like  (@Autowired @InjectMocks) (@Autowired @Mock) (@Autowired @Spy). I think this Annotations works not together with @Autowired

Comment: Where does your spied `OrderService` gets injected? Thats the point I am missing here. Whats your system under test (sut) the spied service needs to get into?

Comment: OrderService gets Injected in the Test, i update the description. I hope its more understandable now.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we have some class with two methods

```
    public class OrderService {

    public String priceIsIncorrect(){
        return "price";
    }

    public String someOtherMethod(){
        return "other price";
    }
}
```

Following test class will mock one method and use real implementation of second method:

```
public class SomeRandomTest {
    private OrderService orderService = new OrderService();
    @Test
    public void test(){
        OrderService spy = Mockito.spy(orderService);
        Mockito.when(spy.priceIsIncorrect()).thenReturn("Spied method");
        System.out.println(spy.priceIsIncorrect()); //will return "Spied method"
        System.out.println(spy.someOtherMethod()); //will return "other price"

    }
}
```

Comment: This is not working with @Autowired :(. I need it, because its a integration Test

Comment: have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44455572/using-spy-and-autowired-together

Comment: it might be that you are creating local spy in before step of each step but later in test you are referencing real (global) autowired object

Answer (score 1):

Try using @InjectMocks and @Mock annotations if you are using Mockito.
Look at the example below
https://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-unit-testing-and-mocking-with-mockito-and-junit

Comment: You shouldn't be using Autowired if you are using MockitoExtension.class. Use @InjectMocks annotation

Comment: Take a look at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing

Answer (score 1):

What I am missing is the key point where your OrderService gets injected to the system under test (sut).

So there are two options:

1. Using Reflection to set the `OrderService` spy instance to the sut
2. IMHO best approach is to try `@SpyBean` on your `OrderService` instancs which AFAIR allows Spies to be used within you Applicationcontext. Give it a try. I'll need to studie the docs later. Maybe I am wrong.

Further: Where does the order service gets invoked within your application?
For me this is not clear based on the provided code.